# ¿Por qué al usar el boton.onclick como contenedor de una función, esta función tenga que ser llamado sin ()?

Tags: javascript

¿cómo están? Mi nombre es Kenyi Zuñiga y recién estoy que aprendo a usar este lenguaje de programación. El día de hoy me he encontrado con esta duda y me gustaría saber por que es que sucede esto. Les comento, estoy tratando de crear en modo de práctica un especie de juego de adivinación en donde la persona tenga que poner un número

y estudiando me he encontrado con esta duda. Me gustaría saber por qué es que al usar el **boton.onclick** como contenedor, esta tenga que ser **llamado** sin el **()**

Aquí abajo dejo mi código completo:

```
boton.onclick = verificar; /* Tengo entendido que para llamar a una función es necesario ponerlo junto a sus (). Por ejemplo, verificar(), sin embargo al ponerno con su () no me funciona. */
```

Aqui les comparto el código completo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Juego Secreto</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<input type="text">
<button>Verificar si acertó.</button>

</body>
<script>
    var secreto = 5;
    var input = document.querySelector("input");

    function verificar (){

        if (parseInt(input.value) == secreto){ 
        alert("Usted acertó.");
        }
        else{
            alert("Usted erró.");
        }
    }

     var boton = document.querySelector("button");  
     boton.onclick = verificar;  /* Esto es la parte del código que no entiendo. No debería ser: verificar() */  

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pones los paréntesis

```
boton.onclick = verificar();
```

lo que estarías haciendo es llamar a la función **verificar** y el resultado que esta devuelve es lo que se le asigna a la propiedad **onclick**, que posiblemente no sea lo que quieres.

Pero lo que realmente quieres es asignarla a la propiedad **onclick** una referencia a tu función, de manera que **onclick** sea como una especie de alias de la función y se pueda llamar a **boton.onclick()** como si fuera la función original.